# Needed: Java library to calculate text readability/complexity

Tags: nlp, text, java

In principle the same as [this](https://pypi.org/project/textstat/) but for Java (and ideally for multiple languages) (e.g. flesch reading ease, smog index, flesch kincaid grade, coleman liau index, automated readability index, dale chall readability score, linsear write formula, gunning fog etc).

I guess there must be plenty of libs but I just cant find them ...

Answer (score 0):

I looked for this as well and found only the unmaintained [RAT](https://github.com/MatthiasHoldorf/readability-analysis-tool) library.

But basically all of these algorithms (most are described as formulas [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.11779.pdf)) can be directly translated [from the single Python file](https://github.com/shivam5992/textstat/blob/master/textstat/textstat.py) with no extra dependencies.

One exception was the Linsear Write formula because of its needing a syllable counting method. But if you use the [CMU pronunciation dictionary](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict) or equivalent, you can easily build the `countSyllables` method and the rest of the algorithm is trivial.